# Spectrum of Klein-Gordon operator in AdS Black Hole

Tags: operators, differential-equations, eigenvalue, klein-gordon-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I'm working on obtaining the spectrum of the Klein-Gordon operator in $AdS_2$ for black hole coordinates. To accomplish that, I first consider the problem in hyperbolic space $H_2$ and then Wick rotate, but I'm having trouble solving for the continuous part of the spectrum.

The eigenvalue differential equation reads
\begin{equation}
-\sinh^2(x) \left[\frac{d^2}{dx^2} - \left(k - \frac{B}{\tanh(x)} \right)^2 \right]\phi(x) = \lambda \phi(x)
\end{equation}

I managed to obtain the discrete spectrum through a variable change
\begin{equation}
y = \coth(x)
\end{equation}
Followed by substituting the solution
\begin{equation}
\phi(y) = (1-y)^\alpha(1+y)^\beta g(y)
\end{equation}
Which resulted in the Hypergeometric differential equation, and eigenvalues $\lambda$ with a dependency on $a \in \mathbb{N}$, from $\textbf{F}(a,b;c;x)$.

However, I'm having trouble finding the path to obtain a spectrum that involves a continuous variable, namely, I tried to reach the hypergeometric equation in a way that would not involve the coefficient $a$ being an integer, or tried transforming it into the Whittaker equation. It may help to know that in the small limit $x \to 0$, the eigenfunctions(for the continuous part) should reduce to Whittaker functions, with eigenvalues:
\begin{equation}
 \lambda = \frac{1}{4} + B^2 + \nu^2, \quad 0 \leq \nu < \infty
\end{equation}